# In perl regex replacements, how to remove leading whitespace for list elements?

Tags: regex, perl, replace, whitespace, element

I use Perl regex to search for a certain pattern, and add some new stuff immediately following it. The added stuff is a list, as commonly expected, I want each element of the list to occupy one line in the output. My code is like:

```
push(@happy_list, "e\n");
push(@happy_list, "f\n");
push(@happy_list, "g\n");
push(@happy_list, "h\n");

$_ = "aaa\nfoo\nbbb";
$_ =~ s/(aaa.*?bbb)/$1\n@happy_list/sg;
print;
```

Output result is:

```
aaa
foo
bbb
e
 f
 g
 h
```

In the output, there is a whitespace at the beginning of each element of the list, just in front of the list element. It's fine, just a little bit ugly, though. Any handy tricks to remove the extra space?

Comment: Could you please add some sample input and output and how exactly you want the output to look instead?

Comment: Just updated post, added code snippet and sample output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appens because the array is used in string context, so the default delimiter is a space.

You can change this by doing `$" = '';` before the substitution.

```
$_ = "aaa\nfoo\nbbb";
$" = ''; #"for syntax highlighting
$_ =~ s/(aaa.*?bbb)/$1\n@happy_list/sg;
print;
```

You can also do:

```
$_ = "aaa\nfoo\nbbb";
my $str = join('', @happy_list);
$_ =~ s/(aaa.*?bbb)/$1\n$str/sg;
print;
```

Comment: Yes, the `$"='';` solution works perfectly with my code. Thank you~! :-)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to trim it?

```
$_ =~ s/^\s+//;
```

Answer (score 1):

First off - I'd suggest *don't* use `$_` like that. It's a reserved variable in `perl`, and is used as a loop iterator. Modifying it is sometimes needed as part of the looping operation, but setting it as a shorthand for the `print;` statement is bad style.

The root of this problem is in stringifying an array - and it's something you don't actually need to do here anyway.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @happy_list;

push(@happy_list, "e\n");
push(@happy_list, "f\n");
push(@happy_list, "g\n");
push(@happy_list, "h\n");

my @new_list; 
push ( @new_list, "aaa\n", "foo\n", "bbb\n" ); 
print @new_list, @happy_list;
```

Although, I'd probably suggest not adding the line feed, and instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @happy_list;

push(@happy_list, "e");
push(@happy_list, "f");
push(@happy_list, "g");
push(@happy_list, "h");

my @new_list; 
push ( @new_list, "aaa", "foo", "bbb" ); 
print join "\n", @new_list, @happy_list;
```

Comment: Thanks! The posted Perl code is not the real code I'm using; it's adapted from a longer code and simplified to demonstrate my question. Yet your post is always enlightening and insightful, thank you~ !